# Сравнение вложенных объектов и массивов в js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Я делаю 2 копии объекта, в последствии их нужно сравнить.
В исходном объекте есть массив

```js
let init = {
 prop1: 'qwerty',
 prop2: 123,
 prop3: [
   {id: 1, val: 'test'},
   {id: 2, val: 'test2'},
   {id: 3, val: 'test3'}
 ],
}

let copy1 = {...init};
let copy2 = {...init};

let res = JSON.stringify(copy1) === JSON.stringify(copy2);
console.log(res);
```

Почему-то при копировании объектов иногда нарушается порядок элементов в массиве из-за чего `res = false`. Как корректно сравнивать такие объекты и с более сложной структурой?

Comment: `let copy1 = {...init};` если не ошибаюсь то в этом случае по `prop3` в обоих копиях будет одним и тем же, так как ссылка. Для копирования *сложных* объектов можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями, например *lodash* предоставляет функцию которая осуществляет [полное копирование](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep), а так же функцию для [сравнения объектов](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual)

Comment: в предоставленном виде порядок не может поменяться

Answer (score 1):

Спред синтаксис не копирует в глубину - в вашем примере prop3 один и тот же объект

Объекты рекурсивно обходить, потому что не каждый объект можно сериализовать

Эта задача решена во многих библеотеках, самая известная это lodash